# Slow operations in the Model-View-Presenter pattern

Tags: winforms, model-view-controller, user-interface, swt, mvp

How do you handle slow operations in the Model-View-Presenter (or MVC or M-V-VM or whatever variant you are using)?

When you have a slow operation in WinForms or SWT/JFace or whatever desktop framework you are using, you have to run it on a background thread to avoid completely locking up the application. Where do you handle this?

I can see a couple of solutions, but I am not entirely happy with any of them:

1. Have the view call always call the presenter on a background thread. That means that the view have to handle that all invocations from the presenter probably will come from a background thread.
2. Have the view call the presenter on the main thread. The presenter will then have to call back into the view when performing a slow operation, so that it can be run in the background.

What do you usually do?

**EDIT:** I just saw this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ThreadedExecuter.aspx . It is basically an implementation of 2. Have anyone tried anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

the view could call the presenter from the main thread. The presenter then starts the operation in a worker thread. And the view (e.g. with a timer) polls the presenter from the main thread, to prevent callbacks into the view. Regards, tamberg

Comment: Do you mean (1)? If the presenter is called on the main thread, the timer would not run, while the presenter is blocking the main thread. But that is an option, too, yes - I am just not certain that it is better than the other options. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I use a pretty similar approach to tamberg (i.e. using worker threads to do the processing).

The main difference is the interaction with the view and the presentation model, which holds extra state that the view directly binds to for behavior such as:

- input disabling
- progress updates (fairly trivial using BackgroundWorker)
- completion notification

By putting the extra state in the presentation model instead of the view, I'm able to swap views (or what is the more common case, have two views point to the same presenter).

Answer (score 1):

you could use the same asynccallback  approach used in server to client side frameworks like GWT , just write a service witch implements your operations and instead of returning your result in standard method return , use a callback interface as an argument o your method

example :

```
class ServiceX {
     void doFoo(x arg , y arg2 , callback arg3){
          //do in your thread 
          arg3.success("with return variables you need")

          // or
          arg3.failed("with exception for example");

     }

}

interface Callback {
     void success(args...);
     void failed(args ...);
}


in your view :

// do 
ServiceX bar = // get your service

bar.doFoo(a1,a2,new CallBack(){
    void succes(args ...){
    }

    void failed(args ...){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used [aop](/questions/tagged/aop) to handle this. All calls to view methods are intercepted and synchronized to the UI thread. We configured our AOP framework (spring.net) to do this for all interfaces that inherit from our `IView` base interface. On presenters we use attributes to indicate that this slow-running operation should run in the background. Presenter methods look something like this:

```
// ...
[RunInBackground]
public void TakeSomeTimeToRetrieveSomeItems
{
  var items = _svc.GetSomeItemsFromTheWeb();
  _view.ShowItems(items); // synced to UI automatically; blocks in presenter
}
```

In the view, we don't have to do anything special:

```
// ...
public void ShowItems(IList<Item> items)
{
  itemBindingSource.DataSource = items;
}
```

Using AOP isn't trivial if your unfamiliar with it, but in this particular case it saved us tons of infrastructure code in the UI and now we can develop a responsive UI with virtually zero effort.